# The plural of "vena cava"

Tags: etymology, grammatical-number, latin

The plural of the English loadword **vena cava** from Latin is **venae cavae**. What are the etymological and grammatical reasons for this plural? Why are both words in a single term pluralized? And are there other similar terms in English?

Comment: plural feminine nouns of the first declension end in -ae in nominative and vocative case, and case of adjectives is governed by the noun the modify. now the fun for you of learning of latin morphology...

Comment: The plural of the French loan words *chaise longue*, *bon mot*, and *agent provacateur* really should be *chaises longues, bons mots* and *agents provacateurs*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phrase "vena cava" [literally translates](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=vena+cava) from the Latin "hollow (like a cave) vein".

In Romance languages, [the adjective is pluralized with the noun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romance_plurals), hence "venae cavae".

As for examples of other plural Latin phrases in English; these are rare. The only I find is "[almae matres](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/alma_mater)" as the technically correct, but increasingly unused, plural of "alma mater".